# How do i retrieve a specific month? Now its retrieving all the months in my graph

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS TotalGuestBook_TotalCount, 
    MONTH(GuestBook_CreatedDate) AS month
FROM
    tbl_Guestbook
GROUP BY
    MONTH (GuestBook_CreatedDate)
```

Comment: But month is not a column name in my database  so i cant use WHERE month = the month as month will then be an invalid column name @Stidgeon

Comment: WHERE MONTH(GuestBook_CreatedDate) = (month you want)

Comment: I would not use _month_ as output name (`as month`) if there already is a function _month()_. You are not even using the output name.

Comment: What is the "graph" you are talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to describe your question not just on the title and give a simple query. what i can get from your script and try to understand is this :

```
SELECT count(*) AS TotalGuestBook_TotalCount, MONTH(GuestBook_CreatedDate) as months
from tbl_Guestbook
where MONTH(GuestBook_CreatedDate) in (the month you want to search)
group by MONTH (GuestBook_CreatedDate)
```

since you want the name, it's easy to be done:

```
SELECT DATENAME(month,datetime) from table.
```

the datename function will help you. but you have to change your query like this:

```
SELECT count(*) AS TotalGuestBook_TotalCount,
       cast(datename(month,GuestBook_CreatedDate)as varchar(20)) as month_name
from tbl_Guestbook
where MONTH(GuestBook_CreatedDate) in (the month you want to search)
group by cast(datename(month,GuestBook_CreatedDate)as varchar(20))
```

if you just want a abbreviation of the month name just cast the varchar(20) to be 3.  like now it will show January, varchar(3) will be Jan

Comment: Thanks!! it works! but how can i change the month from 8 to august? Now is displaying all my data but in numerical form instead of the monthname @Raffaello.D.Huke

Comment: @stewart datename will work that out perfectly hope it will help you :)

Comment: it works!! what if i want to retrieve the months according to the dropdownlist of my month? like for example i select on august, it will retrieve only august. hope you can help (:  @Raffaello.D.Huke

Comment: @stewart then you need declare a variable like date and use it in the where part:    where MONTH(GuestBook_CreatedDate) in (date) you need to input the value from front. if the value is augues not numerica just change the where part:where cast(datename(month,GuestBook_CreatedDate)as varchar(20)) = date since the dropdownlist will only give 1 value, in()  is not necessary

Answer (score 0):

i think You want to retrieve output as :-

```
 select Mon,count(No) NO from(
     select month(GuestBook_CreatedDate) Mon,'1' No from tbl_Guestbook
   )x group by Mon
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use having clause as below

```
declare @month int=1

SELECT 
COUNT(*) AS TotalGuestBook_TotalCount, 
MONTH(GuestBook_CreatedDate) AS month
FROM  tbl_Guestbook
GROUP BY MONTH (GuestBook_CreatedDate) 
having MONTH(GuestBook_CreatedDate)=@month
```